# Unable to upgrade and update

Tags: raspbian

I am unable to upgrade or update my wheezy raspbian OS, before also I had same problems I reinstalled the OS then it worked...

I am using 4GB memory card and now I cant afford to install again because I installed many important packages, because of this issue I am unable to use pi camera. I am stuck and I am unable to proceed (I want to use PI for image processing). Is there any other way to get my camera working? Or fix this update$upgrade, I don't have any problem while installing other softwares. Below are the pictures:

[image: <code>sudo apt-get upgrade</code>]

[image: <code>sudo apt-get update</code>]

Comment: What happens if you try to ping the IP addresses it can't reach?

Comment: lemme try what you said @jacobm0017

Comment: @jacobm0017 nope i cant ping, it says unknown host

Comment: @jacob last timw when i had the same problem i was unable to ping then also, when i reinstalled the os evrything was normal

Comment: But you have access to other sites?

Comment: yeah....i have...

Comment: Are you able to load the web archives at http://archive.raspberrypi.org in a web browser?

Comment: yea..i installled new os(raspbian) in another card...i successfully updated..and upgraded by pi.......may be issue with update and upgrade manager